# Scrape heading of a video using selenium python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-crawler

I want to scrape video name of this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POk-uOQSJVk)  as it is " Insane Woman Goes Crazy On Guy Who Just Wants A Refund".

The code on the web is:

```
<span id="eow-title" class="watch-title" dir="ltr" title="Insane Woman Goes Crazy On Guy Who Just Wants A Refund">
Insane Woman Goes Crazy On Guy Who Just Wants A Refund
```

I am doing in this way:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POk-uOQSJVk")
head = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('watch-title')
print(head.text)
```

It is prompting as:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Is there any wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [`find_elements_by_class_name()` method](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name) *returns a list of `WebElement`s, while you need a single one*. Also, you need to [let the page load until the desired element is present](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=POk-uOQSJVk")

# wait for the presence of the video title
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "eow-title"))
)
print(element.text)

browser.close()
```

Prints:

```
Insane Woman Goes Crazy On Guy Who Just Wants A Refund
```

Comment: Wow.. Booommm... Reached dear... 3 minutes left for accepting the answer.

Comment: it is also working. `head = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('watch-title')
    for ditch in head:
        print(ditch.text)`